# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present , but response has the header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, angularjs

I am using a rails with angularjs and try to login to FB get the

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

After reading up more , i figured out that response header should have the value . So i create custom rack middleware which sends the response with the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' but to my surprise still get the same error . 
This is the request and response i take captured from chrome browser

```
.   Request URL:http://example.com:3000/users/auth/facebook
.   Request Method:GET
.   Status Code:302 Found
.   Request Headersview source
.   Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
.   Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
.   Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
.   Connection:keep-alive
.   Cookie:request_method=GET; _test-cors_session=YUhTOEdYK3NaNm56VnV1NkZCaGRUU2VpQWRhb0pDZVVNc2hkRTFRM3E0dVUwWkJLM3RQand5Y1ZHQVozOXF3NVFVQnlZRGJLNlpVdm1rd0NLbmJUeG9TRExTTjNScVJNaDVhdFg2QnRXUVdYemJyYkt5VnJXcFhnRUJlMFlvaCtNYzZOV3VhNWlGTWpvdGlrTmJ5NUdmd3RJK0VneXlYMG8yMnkyT1hYMHI1czQrTDRybnIvSHREc1JEM2paRHNMLS11Z0xRUTk2TE1Sa3JVYTNieHk1Q3B3PT0%3D--ff30ad1fa1cd900e1270aa8b3dea2bb383973c06; _itinerary_session=BAh7CkkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFVEkiJWRlYWJhNTIyZjk5YjllMTQ5OGQyZWJlZGM0NzQwZTQ0BjsAVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMWRnWFQ2U0VlZUFJZndwUnZNSlEyRHNNVXJJeTM5NFZtcWtZWmtQMUwwdGc9BjsARkkiFG9tbmlhdXRoLnBhcmFtcwY7AFR7AEkiFG9tbmlhdXRoLm9yaWdpbgY7AFQiG2h0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6MzAwMC9JIhNvbW5pYXV0aC5zdGF0ZQY7AFRJIjVhNTE5Y2QwY2ZmODkwZmM1YWJlYjZlNWEyMDFhMjQxZGZiNzgxOWM4NGVkMWFmYWMGOwBG--357be410254e21abbe31911571aaf1642637213f
.   Host:example.com:3000
.   Referer:http://example.com:3000/
.   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
.   **Response Headers**
.   Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
.   Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS
.   Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
.   Access-Control-Request-Method:*
.   Cache-Control:no-cache
.   Connection:Keep-Alive
.   Content-Length:277
.   Content-Type:text/html
.   Date:Wed, 12 Feb 2014 01:05:48 GMT
.   Location:https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=773771049316961&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3A3000%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=email%2Cuser_birthday%2Cread_stream&state=c280fe4f9c321601ff4f54ef29be5581b8653c09511a3172
.   Server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.0/2013-12-25)
.   Set-Cookie:_itinerary_session=BAh7CkkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFVEkiJWRlYWJhNTIyZjk5YjllMTQ5OGQyZWJlZGM0NzQwZTQ0BjsAVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMWRnWFQ2U0VlZUFJZndwUnZNSlEyRHNNVXJJeTM5NFZtcWtZWmtQMUwwdGc9BjsARkkiFG9tbmlhdXRoLnBhcmFtcwY7AFR7AEkiFG9tbmlhdXRoLm9yaWdpbgY7AFQiG2h0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6MzAwMC9JIhNvbW5pYXV0aC5zdGF0ZQY7AFRJIjVjMjgwZmU0ZjljMzIxNjAxZmY0ZjU0ZWYyOWJlNTU4MWI4NjUzYzA5NTExYTMxNzIGOwBG--571ea3be82fba073dff520d63622644ab0c75187; path=/; HttpOnly
.   X-Request-Id:89a5dc292d8442b4daff8b54e9ba6eb7
.   X-Runtime:0.006097
.   X-Ua-Compatible:IE=Edge
```

I tried sending the response as

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

and

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://example.com:3000

but still same error.

PS: I changed localhost to example.com since stackoverflow was not allowing to submit.

Comment: +1 for creating your own middleware